# using the same bind key for objects in different classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, key, bind

I am trying to figure out how to call the same bind key for a movement function here is the setup that I have:

```
Class_A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.object.canvas.bind('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.object.canvas.bind('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)
    def turn_left(self):
        self.x = -7
    def turn_right(self):
        self.x = 7

Class_B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.object.canvas.bind('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.object.canvas.bind('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)
    def turn_left(self):
        self.x = -7
    def turn_right(self):
        self.x = 7
```

But whenever I run the code it only moves class_a

Comment: It seems you are binding the keybind to the `object` type. Are you trying to subclass the Canvas class?

Comment: Yes I am is there any way you can help answer it?

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the Canvas object of tkinter like so

```py
import tkinter as tk

class MyCanvas(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bind('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.bind('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)

    def turn_left(self):
        self.x = -7

    def turn_right(self):
        self.x = 7
```

Comment: Thank You this will help me whenever I need to have a class that connects to just the canvas but I am trying to find out how to use the same bind Left and Right for 2 classes

Comment: I think you forgot `class MyCanvas(tk.Canvas):`.